# When using the same font-size, Sinhala and English give the same font size, but Tamil font size increases.(same font size, but different space takes)

Tags: css, font-size, space, tamil

[image: english, sinhala font size, and tamil font size]

```
@font-face {
   font-family: latoRugular;
   src: url(../../../assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf);
} 

@font-face {
   font-family: notoRegularSinhala;
   src: url(../../../assets/fonts/NotoSansSinhala-Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: notoRegularTamil;
    src: url(../../../assets/fonts/NotoSansTamil-Regular.ttf);
}

* {
   font-family: latoRugular;
   font-family: notoRegularSinhala;
   font-family: notoRegularTamil !important;
  }

body {
   font-family: latoRugular;
   font-family: notoRegularSinhala;
   font-family: notoRegularTamil !important;
}
```

I added the above code, the font family file got from the google-font. So according to the attached picture, We can see English and Sinhala font sizes are small, but the Tamil font size is larger than the English and Sinhala font sizes.

Comment: Exactly which google fonts are you using? (test.ttf doesn't tell us!).

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. The English and Tamil characters are around the same height (both the capitals and lower case in the English typeface sense) while the Sinhala character heights more or less correspond to the English lower case letter heights. Could you describe a bit more what you were expecting?